# How can I create CognitoUser in Android without signup?

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

Typically one would get a CognitoUser object from a prior function. However, I'm trying to just implement a sign-in function currently, so don't need the sign-up function that would return a CognitoUser. How can I create a CognitoUser so that I can authenticate a login? Or is there a better way to authenticate a login?

The constructor for CognitoUser is protected.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out right as I posted it.

You can create an empty CognitoUser by calling getUser() on an initialized UserPool.

Specific code (excluding initializations and obvious boilerplate):

```
user = userPool.getUser();
AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(email, password, null);
user.authenticateUserInBackground(authenticationDetails, authenticationHandler);
```